# How to connect to remote database with windowsphone

Tags: sql, database, windows-phone-8, remote-server

In my app, I want to read a remote sql database. After spending some hours on searching the net, I found out that this can not be done with sql commands but that it needs a webservice wrapper I.E WCF or ADO.net

Are there (and where) any examples on how to read/write records to a remote database server using windowsphone.

Thanks,

Bart

Comment: Is there no one who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option will be to use WCF Data Services with an AD.NET Entity Framework model (there even is a client for Windows Phone). Beware that the Windows Phone client by default does not use compression and does not use the compact json format. UPDATE: Latest client/server parts now use json with Windows Phone

Comment: is there a tutorial which explains this in more detail? if so, where can i find this.

Comment: LMBTFY: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394007(v=vs.105).aspx